# Passing data around with delegation

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I'm trying to understand how delegation works with respect to passing data around. I think that both of the following statements are true:

**UITableView Example**

A `UITableView` object defines protocols for both `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` and a delegate can conform to these protocols. For example, if you have a `UITableView` instance inside a `UIViewController`, people often make the `UIViewController` conform to `UITableViewDataSource`, in which case the `UIViewController` is a **delegate** of the the `UITableView`. In this paradigm, the delegate sends data back to the `UITableView`.

**UIViewController Example**

Often we need to pass data between `UIViewControllers`. One way to do this is to define a delegate relationship between two `UIViewControllers`. We might have a `ParentViewController` and a `ChildViewController` and we wish to send data from the `ChildViewController` to the `ParentViewController`. To set this up, we define a `protocol` in `ChildViewController` and add a delegate property, something like: `@property (weak) id <SendDataToParent> delegate;`. Then if we're using segues we might do something like:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"childvc"]) {
        self.childVC = (ChildViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        self.childVC.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

Then when some event happens in `ChildViewController`, we call `[delegate sendData];` or some such method. In this example, we're passing data from the delegating class to the delegate.

Are these both fine ways to implement a delegate relationship in Objective-C?

Comment: The second one yes, the first one I would say only partial. the first one is a mix of "classic" delegate pattern regarding the `UITableViewDelegate`, but the `DataSource` is more likely part of the ModelViewController pattern (which although uses delegates). I would not recommend thinking in absolutes about these kind of patterns. Just my 2 cents, dont take any of that for certain truth since I like to *use* the patterns, not to know every single correct technical theoretical term for it ;)

Comment: In the first one DataSource is a bit different, but there's also a UITableViewDelegate.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it the first example is the primary reason for the delegate pattern. It comes from the idea that the object implementing the delegate pattern should be reusable and completely agnostic of context, and thus need no subclassing at all to be useful. For example the table view has no context about what app it is in. Basically it says to the delegate - "Hey, give me the stuff to display in row xx" or "Hey, row yy was clicked, should I highlight it?". To me this is a good way of implementing reusable objects that do not need subclassing to take on different functions in different apps. For example more complex UI elements.

In the second example there is a need to communicate between two custom classes in an app, which is also a typical scenario. To do that obviously they need to agree on what messages to send and to have reference to each other. In principle this is like any other messaging interface between two classes and I think in most cases there is no need to complicate it with a delegate pattern. However if the intent is that the child view controller could be reusable and find itself a child of different parent view controller classes then a delegate pattern with bespoke protocol makes sense again.